# Flutter Sliver: Problem on TabBarView with SliverFillRemaining

Tags: flutter

At first sorry about my language, I'm not English :)

I have a problem nothing is displayed when I try to do the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/View/Acces/acces_app.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/View/Acces/acces_trait.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/model/model_form.dart';

class AccesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String droit;
  final User user;
  final Traitement traitement;
  const AccesPage(
      {required this.droit, required this.user, required this.traitement});

  @override
  State<AccesPage> createState() => _AccesPageState();
}

class _AccesPageState extends State<AccesPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabController controller =
        TabController(length: 2, initialIndex: 0, vsync: this);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              elevation: 1,
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 0.2,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/Images/logo.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.help),
                    color: Colors.amber[700],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  const Tab(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                  const Tab(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_left),
                  )
                ],
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TabBarView(
                          controller: controller,
                          children: [
                            const Text('data1'),
                            // AccesTrait(
                            //     traitement: widget.traitement, user: widget.user),
                            const Text('data')
                          ],
                          
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.blue[900],
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showButonEdit(context, widget.droit);
        },
        tooltip: '',
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.edit,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }

  void showButonEdit(BuildContext context, String droit) {
    if (droit == 'admin') {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) {
            return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text('Voulez-vous modifier ce traitement ? '),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text('OUI'),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text('NON'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ));
          });
    }
  }
}
```

But when compiling I get a problem:

`The following assertion was thrown building SliverFillRemaining(child: Column, mode: [scrollable]): A RenderRepaintBoundary expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverFillRemainingWithScrollable.`

My version for flutter is :

Flutter 2.5.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cc385b4b8 (7 days ago) • 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
Engine • revision f0826da7ef
Tools • Dart 2.14.0

ty for your help and have a nice day :)

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using  `Column` inside `SliverList`? Can you include an image that you like to archive?

Comment: Hello, It's true that I don't have the utility of using column, but I thought it was a big problem.
I don't want to include an image at this time. I already have a directory with my images and it works fine on my other pages.
The real problem it's this slivers with SliverList.

Comment: Now my problem is : `The following assertion was thrown building SliverFillRemaining(child: TabBarView, mode: [scrollable]):
A RenderRepaintBoundary expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverFillRemainingWithScrollable.`

Comment: It's tough for me to tell without knowing about ui, and you try removing `sliverList` while `SliverFillRemaining` will take the available spaces.